Can dplyr::mutate function modify a column's value by the index of this column?
For example:
df = data.frame(A=c(1,2), B=c(3,4))
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(.[[2]] = .[[2]] + 1)

This code will not run.
The code:
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(B = .[[2]]+1)

can run. So I want to know if there is a way to replace 'B' with col's index(in this case,it's 2)

Please note that your 2nd example should also return an error.

Use across:
> df |> mutate(across(2, ~ .x + 1))
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5

With grouped dataframes, you'll need to adjust the index accordingly:
> df |> group_by(A) |> mutate(across(1, ~ .x + 1))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   A [2]
      A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     5


This variation would not need adjustment:  df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(across(names(.)[2], ~ .x + 1))

This is how I would do it so that the code remains the same irrespective of number of grouping variables and without hardcoding the index number.
library(dplyr)

col = names(df)[2]

df %>% mutate({{col}} := .data[[col]] + 1)

The same code would also work when you have group_by column.
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate({{col}} := .data[[col]] + 1)


This uses df twice so if its name is changed then it has to be changed in two places.  Suggest first assigning df to df2 and then use the code shown but with df2 in place of df so that it only has to be changed in one spot if the name of df changes.  Alternately make it into a function in which case we can use the name of the formal argument.
